# Update PHP Mongo Extension to 1.5 on Ubuntu 14

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

PHP and Mongo are working correctly however the php5-mongo extension needs updating.

Currently it is version 1.4.5, version 1.5.x is required to be compatible with the latest https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/

Running does not update the version.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mongo
```

Additional info

- mongod --version db version v2.6.12
- php --version PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14

How can the extension be updated?  Is pecl required to perform the update?

Comment: Please explain what information is missing before down voting, I've searched previous questions and could not find an answer.

Comment: In most cases, 'sudo pecl install mongo' would install the latest version available. Try that :-)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I could pick the package from ubuntu vivid but this works.  Had to modify the cmd for 32bit `sudo pecl install --nocompress mongo`

Answer (score 14):

Try with PECL

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Sometime you may get SSL error when connecting to the mongodb so please install dependencies before the pecl installation

```
sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
sudo pecl uninstall mongodb
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

You should add "extension=mongodb.so" to php.ini

Verify the MongoDB extension and module by using

```
sudo php --ri mongodb | grep version
sudo apt-cache policy php-mongodb
```